# Rails JSON Parsing - undefined method `latitude' for "61.3.25.97":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing an API Call as below

```
ipaddr = remote_ip()
    ip2latlng = HTTParty.get("https://freegeoip.net/json/#{ipaddr}")

    render plain: ipaddr.latitude.to_yaml
```

Am getting the following error

```
undefined method `latitude' for "61.3.25.97":String
```

API Return JSON:

```
{
  "ip": "61.x.25.xxx",
  "country_code": "IN",
  "country_name": "India",
  "region_code": "19",
  "region_name": "Karnataka",
  "city": "Bangalore",
  "zipcode": "",
  "latitude": 12.9833,
  "longitude": 77.5833,
  "metro_code": "",
  "area_code": ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you used the wrong variable, and should have been:

```
ip2latlng.latitude.to_yaml
```